# Upgraded Infragistics and my application is not allowing Ultrawingrid to be editable anymore

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an application that uses the Ultra Win Grid and has a column with a check box in it.  It used to be that when I clicked on the check box it would allow you to edit it but now you can't.

Already checked and I am setting CellClickAction to Edit and CellActivation to allow edit.

I used to be using 6.3 and upgraded to 9.1.  The problem started as soon I changed the application to reference they new assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a OnMouseDown event handler that was put in to make it so when you right clicked on a row that row would be selected.  At some point this was changed to not just handle right clicks but any click.  Apparently, selecting the row interfered with the check box being edited.

Fix was to change it to only be on right click.